# sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: columns argument to select() must be a Python list or other iterable

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

New to Python and SQLquery. I am trying to query an existing table in mssql. First task is displaying what is in the table, the other tasK i also want to do is do an exists() statment to check if the data in the table does exist. These are me code snippets so far:

```
def dbhandler():
    params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(db_string)
    engine = db.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(params))

    connection = engine.connect()
    metadata = db.MetaData()
    odfs_tester_history_files = db.Table('odfs_tester_history_files', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
    odfs_tester_history = db.Table('odfs_tester_history', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
    tables_dict = {'odfs_tester_history_files': {'engine': engine, 'connection': connection, 'table': odfs_tester_history_files}, 'odfs_tester_history': {'engine': engine, 'connection': connection, 'table': odfs_tester_history}}
    #return {'engine': engine, 'connection': connection, 'table': odfs_tester_history_files}
    return tables_dict

db_instance = dbhandler()
odfs_tabletest_dict = db_instance['odfs_tester_history']
foo_col = db.sql.column('CSV_FILENAME')
sql = db.select(odfs_tabletest_dict['table']).where(odfs_tabletest_dict['odfs_tester_history'].c.foo_col == '06_16_2020_FMGN519.csv')
df = pd.read_sql(sql, odfs_tabletest_dict['connection'])
print(df)
```

**However when I run the code, I get the following error: sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: columns argument to select() must be a Python list or other iterable. How can I fix this? Also how can i use an exists statement to check if the data in question, the .csv file is in the table and just return a true or false value for me to use as duplicate check?**

Comment: Wow, nobody got any ideas?

Comment: In my case, I resolved this issue by upgrading the sqlalchemy package to the latest version.

Answer (score 7):

In Case anyone runs into this issue, I fixed it by putting square brackets around my table object. I have no idea why this works and neither does my mentor. He had similar code and it worked for him without the need for a [ ].

```
sql = db.select([odfs_tabletest_dict['table']]).where(odfs_tabletest_dict['table'].c.CSV_FILENAME == '06_16_2020_FMGN519.csv')
df = pd.read_sql(sql, odfs_tabletest_dict['connection'])
```

Comment: Be aware of the version(s) of SQLAlchemy in play. The `select` method is in the process of changing so if you are using 1.3.x and your mentor is using the latest master branch (which will eventually become 1.4, and later, 2.0) then you might experience different behaviour.

Comment: reason is because version `1.3.x` uses this documentation with the `[]` https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

Gord Thompsons comment on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62582937/10126125) helped me to fix this. I upgraded to SQLAlchemy 1.4.11 and got rid of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still facing this issue, as a previous answer mentioned, be aware of the version,

I am on version '1.3.10', and what you need is to pass model.columns to the select()

```
model = db.Table('my_table_name', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
query = db.select(model.columns)
```